# Multiple ChoiceType, array expected

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, symfony-forms

I am trying to make a multiple-select `ChoiceType` in my Symfony form. However, I am getting the following error:

> Unable to transform value for property path "[organisations]":
>   Expected an array.

*Note: If I change the name of the component from `organisations` to anything else, it's rendering the form correctly.*

As far as I can see, `organisations` *is* an array:

```
/**
 * @var Organisation[]
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Booking\Entity\Organisation", inversedBy="users")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="users_organisations")
 */
protected $organisations;
```

Here's the form:

```
$organisations = $doctrine->getRepository('Booking\Entity\Organisation')->findAll();

$builder
    ->add('organisations', ChoiceType::class, array(
        'choices' => $organisations,
        'choice_label' => function($organisation, $key, $index) {
            return $organisation->getName();
        },
        'multiple' => true
    ))
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you post the entire exception thrown? This is probably not because of the model but rather what data you submit to the form field.

Comment: @Martin I just added some extra details to the question. If I change `organisations` to anything else, the form is rendered correctly

Comment: Well, can you post the entire exception trace stack and you form definition?

Comment: Why won't you use `EntityType` instead? It would be simpler.

Comment: @dragoste Using `EntityType` did the trick. Thank you

Comment: What exactly did you change to EntityType? I'm having the same issue too.

Answer (score 3):

Use `EntityType` instead.

```
$builder
    ->add('organisations', EntityType::class, array(
        'choices' => $organisations,
        'choice_label' => function($organisation, $key, $index) {
            return $organisation->getName();
        },
        'multiple' => true
    ))
```

<sub><sup>I posted this just because people (like me) don't usually read all the comments. Merit goes to Jakub.</sup></sub>

Comment: It will be prefect to mention about your Github issue too => https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/23192

Comment: Nice find ;) I don't think it's useful, I just misread the doc.

Comment: But error is same also same case of try to make select choose with Entities classes